Preventing exceptions in Python due to print/string format errors?
Is there a way in Python to avoid having print()/string formatting errors throw an exception, without wrapping every print() in a try-except block?  Specifically, to avoid premature termination of long-running jobs due to trivial string formatting mistakes?
I was developing a very long-running program in Python, and making heavy use of print() statements to sanity check program flow.  Each step in the program was very long running.  Too many times I had silly typos or similar mistakes in my print() statements.  So the program would halt when an exception was thrown.
Here's a grossly simplified example:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time

def pre_compute():
    print('running long-running complex function...')
    time.sleep(3) # pretend this is a long-running, complex function
    return 5

def finalize(precomp_val):
    return 1 + precomp_val

x = pre_compute()

#print(f'pre_computed value={x}')  # this is what I meant, but...
print(f'pre_computed value={val}') # ...I accidentally did this

final = finalize(x)

print(f'final value={final}')

The above example will throw an exception:
$ ./print_exception.py
running long-running complex function...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "print_exception.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(f'pre_computed value={val}') # ...I accidentally did this
NameError: name 'val' is not defined. Did you mean: 'eval'?

In this case, I lost all the interesting work due to a silly-but-easy-to-make mistake that, ironically, was meant to help me validate/debug the interesting code.  (And it doesn't necessarily have to be debug prints, maybe I'm using the logging module because I want some intermediate values logged: the same problem can still present.)
This is trivially fixed once discovered, but imagine encountering this time and time again during the development process - it really hurts productivity.
How do most people get around this?  Some thoughts I have, not sure if there are others:

Enclose every print/logger call in a try-except block
Create some kind of wrapper my_print()-type function that catches the exception?  This approach appears to require something fancy, as I tried it in the example above, but the exception is actually in the f-string (before print() is even involved)
Use some kind of pre-run checker tool


as you've noted, this actually has nothing to do with print but with the string formatting.

You just unit-test your code in a way that tries out all the code in reasonable timescale.

You can also use a linter like Ruff. It's super fast and will catch errors like this. Additionally, you can add a pre-commit hook so that linter is run every time you make a commit.

A decent IDE like PyCharm will warn you about references to nonexistent variables while you're coding.
